# iPhone in-app purchases

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

How do you test an in-app purchases before your app is submitted to Apple, let alone accepted or released?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple docs have plenty of info but it's rather vague in places. You may try to read this:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: @diwup: Thanks for the posts, the link looks great. I've got it working without this, the docs are pretty good - my gaff was to be in simulator at first, not on the device.

Comment: @all: I'm a bit surprised in-app purchases start at $1, that's a bit steep and doesn't leave much room for apps that already cost $1. I'd expected these to start from around $0.50 before I looked into this.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to self: RTFM and in particular *be sure to test on the device*, not in the simulator. Simulating in-app purchases explicitly does not work: The console reads " WARNING: SKPaymentQueue does not work in the simulator".